# generate client wsimport miss link between two object

Tags: java, xml, xsd, wsdl, wsimport

I would like to generate client stubs from a wsdl with wsimport maven plugin , this is works well but with one issue : i have two object that should be linked togerther but afetr the generation is donne , it's not perfect

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.hello.com/ns/xsd/boba/restitution-restituerCarriereAvecValo.xsd">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.hello.com/holla/infosRetour.xsd" schemaLocation="xsd/infosRetour.xsd"/>


      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.hello.com/ns/wsdl/boba/messageRetourModuleValorisation.xsd" schemaLocation="xsd/messageRetourModuleValorisation.xsd"/>

      <xsd:element name="messageIn" type="xsd:anyType"/>
      <xsd:element name="messageOut">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="ir:infosRetour">
              <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="messageRetour" type="xsd:anyType"/>
                <xsd:element name="rejetControleSyntaxiqueSemantique" type="xsd:anyType"/>
                <xsd:element name="rejetControleIdentification" type="xsd:anyType"/>
              </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:extension>
          </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
```

here my object `messageOut` sould have a field `messageRetour` of type `messageRetour` class, but when i see my class `messageOut` this field is set as Object and not the montioned class.

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "messageRetour",
    "rejetControleSyntaxiqueSemantique",
    "rejetControleIdentification"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "messageOut")
public class MessageOut
    extends InfosRetour
{

    protected Object messageRetour;
    protected Object rejetControleSyntaxiqueSemantique;
    protected Object rejetControleIdentification;
```

as you can see here here is the sub class generated , you can see that there is a class named `messageRetour`

[image]

HOW CAN I CHANGE THIS TYPE TO BE SET AS A CLASS AND NOT AS OBJECT ?

even when i chnage this line `<xsd:element name="messageRetour" type="xsd:anyType"/>` to `<xsd:element name="messageRetour"/>` i got the same issue always Object and not a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `Object` because of `xsd:anyType` as type.

You should change the type of `<xsd:element name="messageRetour" type="xsd:anyType"/>` to the `messageRetour` type.

This type is probably provided by one of the schemas you import. I'm not sure about the specific name, will be probably `MessageRetour` or `messageRetour` or `message-retour`, something like that. So it will probably be something like:

```
<xsd:element name="messageRetour" type="ir:messageRetour"/>
```

If the type is provided by the other imported schema, you may need to declare a namespace prefix first (like `xmlns:mrmv="http://www.hello.com/ns/wsdl/boba/messageRetourModuleValorisation.xsd"`) and then use `mrmv:messageRetour` as type.

Comment: i post an update on your recommendation you can see it thank you, as response

Comment: i forgot to ask this question: the only way here to refer my object is to use ref instead of type, because my xsd defintiion file begain with <xs:element> and not <xs:complexType>or <xs:simpleType>

Comment: @Feres.o You can do `<xs:element ref="mrmv:messageRetour"/>`. However the element will be in the `mrmv` namespace. If you need your normal namespace, extract the type of `mrmv:messageRetour` into a named type and use it. This is actually a better way.